# Rails 4+ prepared statements with parameterized subqueries produce "$1" instead of substituting parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, prepared-statement

I notice that in Rails 4.2+, `.to_sql` on an ActiveRecord relation no longer substitutes parameters into subqueries. (There's some related discussion in this [github thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18379).) Here's an example:

```rb
ExampleModel.where(network_id: 5150).as("subquery").to_sql
# (Rails 4) => (SELECT "example_models".* FROM "example_models" WHERE "network_client_device_stats"."network_id" = $1) subquery
# (Rails 3) => (SELECT "example_models".* FROM "example_models" WHERE "network_client_device_stats"."network_id" = 5150) subquery
```

How should I adjust my paradigm going forward so that parameterized subqueries work?
In the error I'm examining, the subquery gets embedded into a larger query, and of course, the query fails because of the $1 in it.

Comment: @engineersmnky, alas, it makes no difference.

Comment: In that case you could change the where clause to use arel instead eg. `where(ExampleModel.arel_table[:network_id].eq(5150))` this will not use bind variables but will still perform all necessary escaping.